# Keep fill of SVG pattern centered in animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have an animated SVG in which the origin is the center. There is 256x256 path that is centered around the origin. This path has a fill which is a pattern that is a gradient rect also of 256x256. The path is animated to expand to the full width and height of the viewbox. Ideally, I would like the path's fill to stay centered around the origin, however, it stays in the top left of path, therefore moving with the animation.

I've tried animating the fill (`x`, `y` and `transform` properties) to fake the fill staying centered however this has cros-browser issues. I tried animating all the properties in both CSS and plain SVG and each way tends to work on one browser not the other. For example, the `animateTransform` spline easings don't work on Chrome, but they *do* on FireFox. Alternatively, the CSS cubic-bezier animation easings do work on Chrome but *don't* on FireFox.

Here is the current SVG:

```html
<svg
  width="1024"
  height="1024"
  viewBox="-512 -512 1024 1024"
  fill="none"
  overflow="hidden"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
>
  <style>
    #cube {
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #origin,
    #origin_label {
      fill: red;
      stroke: darkred;
      stroke-width: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  </style>

  <circle id="origin" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" />
  <text id="origin_label" x="15" y="30">(0, 0)</text>

  <use href="#cube" stroke-width="2">
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke"
      dur="6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values="#FF9AA2;#FFB7B2;#FFDAC1;#E2F0CB;#B5EAD7;#C7CEEA;#FF9AA2"
    />
  </use>

  <defs>
    <!-- EVERYTHING TOGETHER -->
    <g id="cube">
      <use
        href="#cube_outline"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="16"
        fill="url(#sky_bg)"
      />
    </g>

    <!-- GRADIENT FILL -->
    <pattern
      id="sky_bg"
      x="0%"
      y="0%"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <rect
        width="256"
        height="256"
        x="0"
        y="0"
        fill="url(#sky)"
        id="starpat"
      ></rect>
    </pattern>

    <!-- THICK OUTER LINE-->
    <g id="cube_outline">
      <path>
        <animate
          attributeName="d"
          dur="3s"
          calcMode="spline"
          keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
          repeatCount="1"
          fill="freeze"
          keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1;0.4 0 0.2 1"
          values="M 0 64 L 118 0 L 236 64 L 236 192 L 118 256 L 0 192 Z;
          M 0 0 L 236 0 L 236 0 L 236 256 L 0 256 L 0 256 Z;
          M 0 0 L 1010 0 L 1010 0 L 1010 1010 L 0 1010 L 0 1010 Z"
        />
      </path>
    </g>

    <linearGradient id="sky" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#141417" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#40354a" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I am limited to only CSS, HTML and SVG as any javascript will be sanitised away.
Is it possible to keep the fill centered? Or is there another approach I should take?

Comment: Please use `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` Also you do not need the z-index for the #cube. You can delete it.

Comment: The gradient is lost if I set that, it just becomes a solid colour fill. If I set the width and height to anything more than 0 it is just the solid colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are grouping svg shapes together the width and height of <**g**> tag changes when the cube_outline starts to expand. In order to avoid that i just used a second <**use**> tag and removed the  to avoid grouping and changed the rect to a path to mimic the same animation that outline does before its expansion. Hope this solves your problem.

```html
    <svg
width="1024"
height="1024"
viewBox="-512 -512 1024 1024"
fill="none"
overflow="hidden"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
>
<style>
  #cube_outline,#starpat {
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  #origin,
  #origin_label {
    fill: red;
    stroke: darkred;
    stroke-width: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
</style>
  
<circle id="origin" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" />
<text id="origin_label" x="15" y="30">(0, 0)</text>
  <use
    href="#cube_outline"
    stroke-linejoin="round"
    stroke-width="16"
  />
  <use
    href="#starpat"
  />
<defs>
  <!-- EVERYTHING TOGETHER -->

  
  <!-- GRADIENT FILL -->
    <path
      width="256"
      height="256"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      fill="url(#sky)"
      id="starpat"
    >
      <animate
        attributeName="d"
        dur="1.5s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keyTimes="0;1"
        repeatCount="1"
        fill="freeze"
        keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1"
        values="M 0 64 L 113 0 L 226 64 L 226 187 L 113 246 L 0 182 Z;
        M 0 0 L 226 0 L 226 0 L 226 246 L 0 246 L 0 246 Z;"
      />
  </path>
  
  <!-- THICK OUTER LINE-->
  <g id="cube_outline">
    <path>
      <animate
        attributeName="d"
        dur="3s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
        repeatCount="1"
        fill="freeze"
        keySplines="0.4 0 0.2 1;0.4 0 0.2 1"
        values="M 0 64 L 118 0 L 236 64 L 236 192 L 118 256 L 0 192 Z;
        M 0 0 L 236 0 L 236 0 L 236 256 L 0 256 L 0 256 Z;
        M 0 0 L 1010 0 L 1010 0 L 1010 1010 L 0 1010 L 0 1010 Z"
      />
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke"
        dur="6s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="#FF9AA2;#FFB7B2;#FFDAC1;#E2F0CB;#B5EAD7;#C7CEEA;#FF9AA2"
      />
    </path>
  </g>
  
  <linearGradient id="sky" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
    <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#141417" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#40354a" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
  </svg>
```